# Fetch in IF statement produces output error

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, zapier

I'm working with Asana and Zapier, and am working to GET a Section within a project, and optionally create one if it doesn't exist. This action doesn't exist natively in Zapier.

I used Zapier Code to do the GET, and that code successfully returns the sectionId as either 0, or the actual id from Asana.

In the next action, I'm doing Zapier Code again, and I'm trying to do the POST to create the Section, but only if the sectionId returned by the GET action is 0.

I think the issue I'm having has to do with a lack of understanding of asynchronous programming. But, I was more or less copied the code from the successful GET action into the new action, and changed the HTTP request a bit to be a POST.

If I remove the if statement, then the POST works as expected.

Where I'm getting stuck is wrapping the fetch in an if statement. I've tried to simply wrap it in an if statement (if 0, do the fetch, else, return the ID that's not 0), and create it as a function that I put within the if statement. I've tried a few different configurations of each method, but either way, the error I'm receiving is:

> Bargle. We hit an error creating a run javascript. :-( Error: 
>   ReferenceError: output is not defined

Here's my code:

```
var sId = input.sId;

function doFetch(aPId) {
  var settings = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': "name=Emails%3A"
  };

  var url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/' + aPId + '/sections';

fetch(url,settings)
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    callback(null, json);
  })
  .catch(callback);
}

if(sId === 0){
  return doFetch(input.asanaProjectId);
}

output = [{test: 123}];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. I can't explain it fully, but this worked. I believe the if statement itself was the issue.

```
var sId = inputData.sId;

function createSection(aPId) {
  var settings = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    'body': "name=Emails%3A"
  };

  var url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/' + aPId + '/sections';
  console.log('Settings:',settings);
  console.log('URL:',url);


  fetch(url,settings)
    .then(function(res) {
      var response = res;
      //console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      //console.log(json);
      var sId = json['data']['id'];
      callback(null,{sectionId: sId});
    })
    .catch(callback);

}

if(sId == 0){
  var sId = createSection(input.asanaProjectId);
  console.log('If test ran!');
} else {
  output = [{sectionId: sId}]; 
}
```